# Is it possible to set scrollablity of connection.getMetaData().getExportedKeys() result set?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

Is there any way to set the `ResultSet` object returned from `getExportedKeys()` to a `TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`? I know prepared statements can be initialised to this value, but can `ResultSets` returned from other methods such as `getExportedKeys` or `getImportedKeys` be set to `SCROLL_INSENSITIVE/SENSITIVE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot. The JDBC 4.2 specification explicitly says (page 40):

> The `ResultSet` objects that are returned from a `DatabaseMetaData` method have
>   a sensitivity of `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` and a concurrency of `CONCUR_READ_ONLY`.

And it is impossible to change the scrollability of a result set after creation.

Comment: Thanks I solved it by adding each ResultSet row to an array and scolling through the array as usual.